# How to use POST request for this type array of embedded documents in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i created a cart schema. inside cart schema i have a items property which is an array of movie sub-docs.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    required: true,
  },
  dailyRentalRate: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 255,
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
});

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  dateCreated: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date().getTime(),
  },
  items: [
    {
      movie: movieSchema,
    },
  ],
});

const Cart = mongoose.model("Cart", cartSchema);

exports.Cart = Cart;
```

now i want to use post request so i can create new cart with array of movie

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const { Cart } = require("../models/shoppingCarts");
const { Movie } = require("../models/movie_model");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const carts = await Cart.find().sort("dateCreated");
  res.send(carts);
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const movie = await Movie.findById(req.body.movie);
  if (!movie) return res.status(400).send("Invalid movie Id.");

  let cart = new Cart({
    items: [
      {
        movie: {
          _id: movie._id,
          title: movie.title,
          price: movie.price,
          dailyRentalRate: movie.dailyRentalRate,
          quantity: movie.quantity,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
  await cart.save();
  res.send(cart);
});

module.exports = router;
```

when i use postman to create i gets a error

error: Cannot access 'movie' before initialization ReferenceError: Cannot access 'movie' before initialization

i tried to find solution but i could not.

Comment: Can you precise on which line do you get the error please? Can we have the full error stack?

Comment: I'm no mongoose expert but it sounds like it doesn't recognize your movie schema. I might have have to export it aswell.

Answer (score 0):

What I observed from the code above is:

1. you didn't create and export your Movie model; `module.exports = mongoose.model("Movie", movieSchema)`;
2. When working with subdocuments in mongoose I think one of the best ways of going about it is saving the ObjectId in your MongoDB collection which can later be retrieved by calling the `.populate("model name")` method, see below code;

   ```
   // in your Cart Schema 
   const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       dateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date().getTime(),
         },
       items: [
            {
             type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref: "Movies"
           },
      ],
    });

   // in your post request
    router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const movie = await Movie.findById(req.body.movie);
    if (!movie) return res.status(400).send("Invalid movie Id.");

      let cart = new Cart()
      //do 
       cart.items = movie.id
      //the movie id will be saved in the database
      await cart.save();
      res.send(cart);
   });

   //in your get request
   router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
     const carts = await Cart.find().populate("movies")
     //you should get a detailed response
     res.send(carts);
   });
   ```